# Accesing MASTER_API using roscpp

Tags: ros, c++, master, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to use some functions of the MASTER_API with C/C++ but I'm not finding any references to that. I've already seen a lot of times the pythin code to do that but I'd like to know if there's a C/C++ code to access and use it. I've already know too that we can use XMLRPC, but I have no ideia how to implement that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198373/accesing-master_api-using-roscpp/) by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing you want various methods from the [roscpp](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/) API.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on 2014-11-27**:
Yeah man! That was what I was looking for. Thanks!